# Spring Cache: How to use Cache key based on the response object

Tags: spring, caching

I have these to methods:

```
@Cacheable(value="products")
public Product findByName(String name)
@CacheEvict(value = "products", key="#productId")
public boolean updateProduct(int productID)
```

The product has a field id, which is the key.

Now I have the problem, that themethod findByName still find old objects after using the update-method. I think, the problem, is that findByName strored the object under the key name and not the productId. In the method arguments, I dont have the productId. But I dont know, how I can tell Spring cache to use a property of the returned object.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a field of the returned object as the cache key. Only input parameters are valid for the `key="#someFieldName"` parameter.

If you have trouble with outdated objects, you may need to evict the whole cache after a product update with a differnt key type than the `findByName` method like this:

```
@CacheEvict(value = "products", allEntries = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly common limitation to run inte with the Spring-cache framework. The way I usually design around it, when it becomes an issue, is to include the required parameter in the call that should evict the cache, even if it's not needed. Like so:

```
@CacheEvict(value = "products", key="#productName")
/* productName only needed for CacheEvict... */
public boolean updateProduct(int productID, String productName) {
...
}
```

Comment: Adding parameters didnt work for me, because the clients who calls the method doesnt have these informations and I dont want to request this information from the database before.

Comment: Then you need a tertiary cache where you store mapping between product ids and product names and some logic to look up the name from the tertiary cache (or load it from database if not present) and evict the id cache and the lookup cache based on that information. This can be achieved using spring-cache annotations and some clever facade layering or you can evict the entire cache, but that's not really optimal from a performance viewpoint.