# Spring boot cache on Response DTO

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, spring-cache

I have written below function to get All the pokemons.
Now I want to add the functionality to cache the pokemons by id which is coming from the list. I am using Simple cache for Caching.

Dependency:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache'
```

Cache Config :

```
@Component
public class SimpleCacheCustomizer implements CacheManagerCustomizer<ConcurrentMapCacheManager> {
    @Override
    public void customize(ConcurrentMapCacheManager cacheManager) {
        cacheManager.setCacheNames(List.of("pokemons"));
    }
}
```

Cache Function :

```
public interface PokemonCustomRepository {
    @Cacheable(value = "pokemons", key = "#result.id")
    List<Pokemon> getPokemonByNameAndType(String name, String types, int limit, Long skip, String generation, String sort);
}
```

I tried using above code, it gave me below error.

```
EL1012E: Cannot index into a null value
```

I tried below code :

```
public interface PokemonCustomRepository {
    @Cacheable(value = "pokemons", key = "#result?.each?.id", unless = "#result == null")
    List<Pokemon> getPokemonByNameAndType(String name, String types, int limit, Long skip, String generation, String sort);
}
```

Getting :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null key returned for cache operation (maybe you are using named params on classes without debug info?) Builder[public java.util.List api.pokedex.repository.custom.impl.PokemonCustomRepositoryImpl.getPokemonByNameAndType(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int,java.lang.Long,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)] caches=[pokemons] | key='#result?.each?.id' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='#result == null' | sync='false'
```

So my question is, can we cache the data based on the response coming ?
If yes, how can we do it ? 
And if No, is there any way to do it using spring and not creating the own cache by Map and invoking it every time manually to check for cache hit ?

Comment: Have you checked what is causing that error? ie what value is null that is making the code throw error.

Comment: Added the edit to it, also I think its finding `#result.id` to be null, so I tried with each got from some stackoverflow issues.

Comment: perhaps you could try using the [`unless`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html#unless()) element to check if the `#result.id==null` if that is the case, do not perform the cache?

Comment: now that i think about it, is the use of  `#result` valid? isnt that supposed to refer to the result of the method invocation? Will that cause any issues since i am thinking of something like "it checking for the result id before the result is even computed?"

Comment: Yes, that is what the issue is, I think the same. So i am not sure how can I implement such functionality using cache

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13065152/16034206 https://stackoverflow.com/a/54002606/16034206 seems like you cannot use #result in 
 computing the key for cacheable

Comment: I m thinking you could probably write a helper class w/ helper methods to cache the results after you get the pokemon from your repository. ie `var list = PokemonCustomRepository.getPokemonByNameAndType(...); for (var pokemon : list) { cacheHelper.cachePokemon(pokemon); }` and there you can just directly access the pokemon id, instead of trying to access #result

Comment: Yes, let me try that